# Displaying elements of Arraylist one by one

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Everytime I clicked next button it should display the next element of my arraylist. It is not what's happening. It stays at the first element.

```
JButton btnNext = new JButton("Next");
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
            numbers.add("A");
            numbers.add("B");
            numbers.add("C");                 
            ListIterator litr = numbers.listIterator();               
              if (litr.hasNext()) {                  
                 System.out.print(litr.next());
              }


        }
    });
    btnNext.setBounds(71, 167, 89, 23);
    contentPane.add(btnNext);
```

Obtain output: AAA
Expected output: ABC (for 3 clicks)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For each click you create a new `ArrayList`, add 3 elements to it, create an iterator and obtain the first element from the list via the iterator.
Therefore you always get the same output.

In order to get a different element on each click, you should keep your `ArrayList` and your iterator as members of your class.

For example :

```
public class YourClass
{
    private List<String> numbers;
    private ListIterator<String> litr;

    public YourClass () {
        numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        numbers.add("A");
        numbers.add("B");
        numbers.add("C");                 
        litr = numbers.listIterator();  
    }

    ... 
    btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {              
            if (litr.hasNext()) {                  
                System.out.print(litr.next());
            }
        }
    });
    ...
}
```

Note that after clicking the button 3 times, it will stop producing output, since the iterator will reach the end of your list.

Comment: I get it now =) Thank you for your prompt response!

Answer (score 0):

You recreate the list and the iterator every time the `actionPerformed` method is executed. You have to reuse the same iterator instance however, to achieve the desired result. You could e.g. store the iterator as field in the `ActionListener`:

```
btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    private final ListIterator litr;

    {
        ArrayList numbers = new ArrayList();
        numbers.add("A");
        numbers.add("B");
        numbers.add("C");
        this.litr = numbers.listIterator();
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {           
        if (litr.hasNext()) {                  
            System.out.print(litr.next());
        }
    }
});
```